# Do diatomic isoelectronic molecules have the same bond order even when the octet rule is not followed?

Tags: bond, molecular-orbital-theory, electronic-configuration

It can be observed and [proven that diatomic isoelectronic molecules have the same bond order](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/33765/113406) when they follow the octet rule (upto 3rd period elements). But what about when they do not follow the octet rule like in transition metals? Do they still have the same bond order? If so, why?

Comment: That's not true even for CO vs N2, at least if you use computational methods.

Comment: Isoelectronic molecules have the same _everything_, except nucleus charge. Think of it this way: what is a bond made of? Electrons.

Comment: Do you know many diatomic molecules that do not follow the octet rule , apart from $\ce{NO}$ ?

Comment: @Mithoron Can you elaborate a little or tell me where to start searching? Do you mean that the electronic configurations of CO and N2 are different as given by molecular orbital theory?

Comment: @IvanNeretin Yeah, that's why it makes sense when they follow the octet rule, because all of them have the same number of shared electrons as the goal. But when we do not follow the octet rule, the stabilities of the specific elements are what matters right?

Comment: @Maurice I found CoO, but I haven't found any isoelectronic pairs as you said. So they don't exist? If they do, they are exceptions that don't need to follow this rule about bond order right?

Comment: @Balu. $\ce{CoO}$ is not a molecule. It is a solid made of piles of cobalt(II) and oxide ions.

Comment: @Maurice Oh, does it qualify as an ionic compound though?

Comment: There is no bond order in a pile of ions.

Comment: @Maurice Geez, could you get a bit more advanced here, not just repeat lame high school ideas? I estimate CoO has about the same covalent and ionic bonding component. Also in gas phase, especially extremely diluted, you can have, like, any molecule. In comparison with HeH+, CoO is no biggie at all.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_monoxide#Bonding_and_dipole_moment

Comment: $\ce{CoO}$ is a cobalt oxide. It has nothing to do with $\ce{CO}$. Nothing ! And $\ce{CoO}$ cannot be obtained as a gas. It is decomposed without melting or boiling when heated at 1800°C